# Accept case insensitive prefix in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a text field that contains an http address. A valid input should be the http:// prefix plus a valid IP address.

I would like to enhance my text field in order to consider valid all strings that have a case insensitive "http" prefix.

For example `hTtP://130.14.15.15` is acceptable.

Comment: Show what you currently have and describe what it does wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of testing like `if ([aString hasPrefix:@"http://"])` you could test the lowercase version of the string:

```
if ([aString.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"http://"])
```